# Slice 3-d tensor of Theano

Tags: python, theano, keras

I'm building a chacter-based rnn model using Keras (Theano backend). One thing to note is that I don't want to use a prebuilt loss function. Instead, I want to calculate loss for some datapoints. Here's what I mean.

Vectoried training set and its label look like this:
X_train = np.array([[0,1,2,3,4]])
y_train = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5]])

But I replaced first k element in the y_train with 0 for some reason. So, for example, new y_train is

y_train = np.array([[0,0,3,4,5]])

The reason why I set the first two elements to 0 is I don't want to include them when computing loss. In other words, I want to calculate the loss between X_train[2:] and y_train[2:].

Here's my try.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)  # for reproducibility

from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Embedding
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers.wrappers import TimeDistributed

X_train = np.array([[0,1,2,3,4]])
y_train = np.array([[0,0,3,4,5]])

y_3d = np.zeros((y_train.shape[0], y_train.shape[1], 6))
for i in range(y_train.shape[0]):
    for j in range(y_train.shape[1]):
        y_3d[i, j, y_train[i,j]] = 1

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(6, 5, input_length=5, dropout=0.2))
model.add(LSTM(5, input_shape=(5, 12), return_sequences=True)  )

model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(6)))  #output classes =6
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

from keras import backend as K
import theano.tensor as T
def custom_objective(y_true,y_pred):
    # Find the last index of minimum value in y_true, axis=-1
    # For example, y_train = np.array([[0,0,3,4,5]]) in my example, and 
    # I'd like to calculate the loss only between X_train[3:] and     y_train[3:] because the values
    # in y_train[:3] (i.e.0) are dummies. The following is pseudo code if y_true is 1-d numpy array, which is not true.
    def rindex(y_true):
        for i in range(len(y_true), -1, -1):
            if y_true(i) == 0:
                return i
    starting_point = rindex(y_true)
    return K.categorical_crossentropy(y_pred[starting_point:], y_true[starting_point:])


model.compile(loss=custom_objective,
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_t, batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=1)
```

Comment: and could you explain what your problem is?

Comment: The function "custom_objective" is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Appart from minor errors like the wrong paranthesis in line 35 and a wrong variable name in the last line, there are two problems with your code.

First, the model you defined will return a matrix of probability distributions (due to the softmax activation) for classes at each timestep.
But in `custom_objective` you are treating the output as vectors. You are already correctly transforming `y_train` to a matrix above.

So you would first have to get the actual predictions, the most simplest case is assigning the class with highest probability, i.e.:

```
y_pred = y_pred.argmax(axis=2)
y_true = y_true.argmax(axis=2)  # this reconstructs y_train resp. a subset thereof
```

The second problem is that you are treating these like *real* variables (numpy arrays).
However, `y_true` and `y_pred` are symbolic tensors. The error you get clearly states one of the resulting problems:

```
TypeError: object of type 'TensorVariable' has no len()
```

`TensorVariable`s have no length, as it is simply not known before real values are inserted! This then also makes iteration the way you implemented it impossible.
By the way, in cases where you iterate real vectors you might want to do it backward iteration like this: `range(len(y_true)-1, -1, -1)` to not go out of bounds, or even `for val in y_true[::-1]`

To achieve what you want, you need to treat the corresponding variables as what they are and use methods supplied for tensors.

The center of this calculation is the `argmin` function to find the minimum. By default this returns the first occurrence of this minimum.
Since you want to find the last occurrence of this minimum, we need to apply it to the reversed tensor and calculate it back to an index into the origianl vector.

```
starting_point = y_true.shape[0] - y_true[::-1].argmin() - 1
```

Possibly, there might be an even simpler solution to your problem as it looks like you are trying to implement something like masking.
You might want to take a look at the `mask_zero=True` flag for Embedding layers. This would work on the input side, though.